# Remap keys via xmodmap no longer works

Tags: wayland, xmodmap

I recently switched to Ubuntu 17.10 from Ubuntu 16.04.

So far, I used `xmodmap` to remove Caps_Lock and replace it with the backslash-symbol.

This doesn't seem to work under 17.10 (maybe because `xmodmap` is an X11 app and 17.10 uses Wayland?). Is there another way to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is complicated and and evolving: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292868/how-to-customise-keyboard-mappings-with-wayland for a variety of approaches.

The GNOME Tweak Tool might be your best bet. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/417708/108198

By the way, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS uses Xorg by default.